# case class with 200 attributes gets java.lang.StackOverflowError error and message "That entry seems to have slain the compiler."

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark-shell, trying to create a Scala case class with 200 attribute doesn't work. I get the error bellow saying that it slays the compiler:
I got a suggestion to increase the stack memory:

```
spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss2M" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss2M"
```

That helped initially but when I pass more argument to spark-shell for Kafka and HBase:

```
spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss4M" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xss4M" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/conf/kafka_jaas.conf" --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/conf/kafka_jaas.conf" -classpath /usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol.jar:shc-core-1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11.jar:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/kafka/libs/kafka-clients-0.10.1.2.6.1.0-129.jar --files /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml
```

Same error keep happening:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4504)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
.............

That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replay
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
[y/n]
```

Comment: 200 attributes? Why would you even use something like this?

Comment: you should really format the question correctly, provide code snippets preferably. Also, it should not have [apache-spark] tag

Comment: You might want to raise this as an issue in a compiler. However, 200 attributes seems like a little bit too much indeed. Maybe it would work better if it were represented as a dictionary/map instead? Or a collection of related entities. Might be good to know what are you trying to achieve and why you need to work with 200 attribute case class.